# Get photos from photo table that has been liked by the current user, using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the photos from the photo table, but just those liked by the user.

There is a field in the photo table called like_info, which returns an object with 3 fields, being one of them user_likes: indicates if the current session user has liked this photo (all that I need). https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

I can retrieve this info (like_info->user_likes) but I'm not able to use it inside the query. I've tried

```
SELECT pid, owner, src, like_info FROM photo WHERE pid IN (433368913233690121,433368913233456540) AND like_info.user_likes=1
```

which gives me an error "user_likes is not a member of the like_info scalar".

I know this would work if like_info were an array, but I'd like to know how to do it in this case, being an object.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First that came to my mind is just nesting queries from `like` and `photo` tables:

```sql
SELECT pid, owner, src, like_info FROM photo WHERE pid IN (
  SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() AND object_type="photo"
)
```

Unfortunately I've discovered a bug ([FQL results from `like` table have wrong `object_type`](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/240411569387683)) that doing query above useless (let's hope this will be addressed quickly).

Luckily there is another way to achieve the same results with another (a bit more complicated) query:

```sql
SELECT pid, owner, src, like_info FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (
  SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE id IN (
    SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()
  ) AND type='photo'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with the **like** table.

```
SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() AND object_type="photo"
```

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I could achieve this same objective with the like table (I'd vote you up if my reputation allowed me). But I'm really interested in being able to use this **like_info** in a Where clause, it can be so useful.